# ruby on rails - how do I render html x times

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

how do you render html x times with ruby on rails?

currently I have something `<%= for i in 1..5 do render html:"X" end %>`

but this renders 1..3

how can I make it render XXX? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What does "renders 1..3" mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
# x would be the number of times to render this html
<% x.times do %>
  <%= render html: 'X' %>
<% end %>
```

Not sure why you're doing this, though, the Stack Overflow community may be able to provide a better approach.

Comment: woah! it worked! sorry, I'm completely new at RoR, whats SO?

Comment: also, why does that work, but <%= x.times do render html: 'X'  end %> doesnt?

Comment: Yeah, that's basically a better Ruby syntax for looping. I'm guessing that `for in range` would pick the items within the bounds, not the bounds themselves, in your case `1 and 5`

Comment: Render doesn't add any HTML to the page, all render does is *produce* the HTML, and return it as a string. It's the `<%=` that adds whatever you pass it to the page. But, with `<%= 5.times do some_stuff end %>`... that runs `some_stuff` 5 times, but the _return value_ is still just _5_. It's like the difference between `5.times { puts 'Hello' }` (which prints 'hello' five times) and `puts 5.times { 'Hello' }` (which throws away 'Hello' five times and then prints 5 afterwards).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

```
<% (1..5).each do |i| %>
  <%= render html: "X" %>
<% end %>
```